# vim binary with all libraries statically linked

Tags: compiling, vim, ncurses

I want to build vim with all libraries, which vim depends on, statically linked. Vim version is sufficient to run YouCompleteMe. I use the following flags with configure script:

```
$./configure --with-features=huge \
             --enable-multibyte \
             --enable-rubyinterp \
             --enable-pythoninterp \
             --enable-perlinterp \
             --enable-luainterp \
             --enable-gui=gtk2 \
             --enable-cscope
```

I set LDFLAGS to '-static'

```
$export LDFLAGS='-static'
```

I also installed all vim build dependencies:

```
$sudo apt-get build-dep vim
```

It turns out that there is still something missing because I get the following error message from configure script:

```
checking --with-tlib argument... empty: automatic terminal library selection
checking for tgetent in -ltinfo... no
checking for tgetent in -lncurses... no
checking for tgetent in -ltermlib... no
checking for tgetent in -ltermcap... no
checking for tgetent in -lcurses... no
no terminal library found
checking for tgetent()... configure: error: NOT FOUND!
      You need to install a terminal library; for example ncurses.
      Or specify the name of the library with --with-tlib.
```

I checked if I have static version of ncurses library - yes, I have under the following location:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libncurses.a
```

Without static LDFLAG vim builds without any problem.

Do you have any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Did you see this [so] answer (maybe related): [tgetent() not found while compiling vim](http://superuser.com/a/867019)

Comment: @steeldriver yes, I did - I followed all the advices mentioned there and still have the error in configure script.

Comment: Hmm... so this doesn't seem to be an issue with `tgetent` specifically: if you look in `src/auto/config.log` you will probably see an entry like `/usr/bin/ld: dynamic STT_GNU_IFUNC symbol \`strcmp' with pointer equality in \`/usr/lib/gcc...libc.a(strcmp.o)' can not be used when making an executable; recompile with -fPIE and relink with -pie`. Likely the error just *appears* to relate to the terminal library because that's the first occasion that `./configure` attempts to link anything with your `LDFLAGS='-static'`

Comment: ... the conflicting `LDFLAGS` seem to result from enabling Ruby interpreter support: see if it works when you set `--enable-rubyinterp=NO` - if so that will at least give you somewhere to focus

Comment: @steeldriver it helps - thanks! But I still need rubyinterp in vim to enable YouCompleteMe - do you you have any idea why it is the problem with libc.a?

Comment: I don't think the problem is with libc.a - I think it is how the script configures the linking for rubyinterp. Regardless of whether `--enable-rubyinterp=yes` or `--enable-rubyinterp=dynamic` is used, it appears to supplement LDFLAGS with the output of `ruby -r rbconfig -e "print RbConfig::CONFIG['LDFLAGS']"` - which AFAIK are the LDFLAGS flags used to build ruby itself.

Comment: ... I can't see an easy way around that: you'd need to either (1) modify the configure script to obtain appropriate static LDFLAGS for ruby; or (2) build your own statically-linked version of ruby and point the script at it (possibly using `--with-ruby-command=...`) so that the existing RbConfig command returns appropriate static flags; or (3) hack the ruby RbConfig module somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem when trying some things with pkgsrc on vim port.
Try to open the **config.log** file. In my case, the configure script told me this :

```
| int
| main ()
| {
| char s[10000]; int res = tgetent(s, "thisterminaldoesnotexist");
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:11408: error: NOT FOUND!
      You need to install a terminal library; for example ncurses.
      Or specify the name of the library with --with-tlib.
```

The problem here is that the **termcap.h** header is missing on the C code snippet. So I patched the configure script by adding `#include <termcap.h>` and then it was ok.

I don't know if it the same problem on your platform but you should try :)